# Terraform 0.12v not picking values from .tfvars file (variable type - map/object)

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an ALB(pls see below for code I am using), I am using variable.tf file and while executing **terraform apply** command, I am using dev-terraform.tfvars file (terraform apply -var-file="dev-terraform.tfvars"). But for some reason, the value **private** from dev-terraform.tfvars is not being picked by terraform. Any suggestions please.

ALB module folder Structure

[image]

alb code(main.tf)

[image]

variable file in alb module

[image]

dev-terraform.tfvars file(changed values)

[image]

Comment: I had to rename terraform.tfvars to prod.auto.tfvars  and then it worked. Doesn't make sense both terraform.tfvars and *.auto.tfvars supposed to work.